# Can I have complete control over UIKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I've been frustrated by the lack of extensibility **categories** give the developer. I cannot override getters or setters, let alone define new properties. The question is:

"Is it possible to do these things **WITHOUT** subclassing a UIKit component like `UIView`?"

Subclassing `UIView` has its disadvantages, too. I cannot force components of UIKit that subclass `UIView` (e.g. UIImageView) to *instead* subclass my subclass of UIView. Categories really do work best for what I'm adding to the UIView class, but the limitations I stated earlier are too restricting for my tastes.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your question is far too vague. What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To 'squeeze' more out of a category you may find this helpful. [link](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/) It discusses objects by associative references in objective-C categories.

Comment: It isn't really a UIKit issue; it's more of an Objective-C issue. It would be great to be able to inject anything into any object. But Objective-C is not Ruby; hmm, I wonder whether using something like RubyMotion would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without answering how to do it, I can refer to an [interview with Loren Bricther](http://gigaom.com/2012/12/03/loren-brichter-designs-on-the-future-of-ios-apps/):

> He built his own version of the user interface framework, the software
> that sits right above the graphics processor on an iOS device. Apple
> creates that for developers — it was completely unnecessary for him to
> do this. But this is the kind of thing he considers “fun.”
>
> “It’s insane,” he admitted. “But I wanted to experiment with different ways of driving graphics … Apple’s [UIKit] is the best, but I wanted to try.” The experiment was a resounding success — and now has a million guinea pigs testing his code via Letterpress. And, he said, “there have been zero issues” with what he built.

So it is possible. [Letterpress](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/letterpress-word-game/id526619424?mt=8) is built this way.